# Is the second derivative of $\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ or $L^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

I was unsuccessfully trying to show whether the function

### $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_k \partial x_j}\frac{1}{|x-y|}$

for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is in $L^2$ or in $L^1$? i.e if $\Vert\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_k \partial x_j}\frac{1}{|x-y|} \Vert_{L^2} < \infty $ .

Is it? 
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: is $\frac{1}{|x|^k}$ integrable ?

Comment: Yes but it depends on the bounds of the integrals !

Comment: I thought to pass in polar coordinate but then I have $\int_0^{\infty}$ and $1/|x|^k$ is never bounded ...

Comment: I think it is not since the Laplacian of $1/|x-y|$ is the Dirac delta function.